Disable or help to configure OpenGL in Qt Creator
I'm a newbie in QT Creator, just installed open-source version 6.8 on my Fedora v40. I have OpenGL .so files on my machine. I'm following a simple QT for Beginners article. However, when I build my project (.pro file's code and main.cpp below) I face the following error:

Cannot find -lGL. No such file or directory

I went to my /etc/include and there was no GL.h file or something in there... I only have some .so files in /usr/lib/ ...
Questions: Can I disable OpenGL altogether? I'm not familiar with the libary and not planning on using it at all for my simple project now. OR, how do I resolve the problem linking it to a real header?
main.cpp:
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app (argc, argv);

 QPushButton button ("Hello world !");
 button.show();

 return app.exec();
}

.pro file:
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = MusicApp.pro

QT = core gui
MAKEFILE
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 6): QT += widgets
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp


Edit your question with the full output of the compilation process.

When you say "I have OpenGL .so files on my machine.", can you clarify which ones? Did you install the libglvnd-glx package, which provides a libGL.so.1?

Yes, sorry, I do have libglvnd-glx and libGL.so.1 files in /usr/lib. However, no OGL files in /etc/include.

@Botje the compilation error appears in the mini window, no output is provided. It is a linking error, that is what it says

Okay, so if anyone is struggling with this -lGL, it basically means what it says: the linker is looking for gl.h file in a specified directory (/usr/include in my case) and it can not find it there. What you do to install gl.h:
if you are rpm-based (Fedora):

sudo dnf install mesa-libGL-devel.i686
OR
sudo dnf install mesa-libGL-devel.x86_64

If you are apt based:

sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

Should do.
